# Html div within div hover display block

Tags: html, css

How do I make a `display:none;` div within a div to display the hidden div when I hover over it?

**The code:**

```css
#inside_content{
  display:none;
}
#box:hover #inside_content{
  display:block;  <!--Dosen't work-->
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="inside_content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it better to use class?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works very well. See the following code:

```css
#inside_content {
  display:none;
}
#box:hover #inside_content{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  Show content inside!
  <div id="inside_content">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have content in the div section. Your code

```
<div id="inside_content">
</div>
```